# Get latest release version number for safari, opera, ie and edge browser

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, safari, opera, microsoft-edge

I am trying to figure out a rather stable way to programmatically determine the latest release version number of safari, opera, ie and edge browser.

It doesn't have to be failproof as it's only a nice-to-have-feature I can blend out whenever the result looks "suspicious".

- There seems to be no API or json/xml/csv download (is there?).
- I didn't want to rely on third parties handling that stuff manually.
- If possible I don't want to parse any website output.

I managed to retrieve chrome and firefox versions with the help of following ideas:

- extract a version number from a git repo
- parse a redirected link from a download button
- download the software and look for a version number in one of the info files
- parse an "internal" dashboard

Any sources or ideas would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Out of curiosity: what's the use-case?

Comment: fair question. Internal security dashboard telling people to update their browsers.

Comment: Anyone? Even if you can help out with only a vague idea about one single browser, your answer is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use your software inventory tool and just build a query that compares and pulls the highest version since its likely at least one person will always have the newest version. We use lansweeper, but I am sure system center and a lot of other tools do quality scanning as well. The tool links each machines name, mac address, ip address, and software version.

On the dashboard you could show 
IE:
Most Recent Version  X
Your Current Version X
etc etc etc

Would be a few simple queries based on the dashboard viewers machine IP

Comment: Thanks @Kyle Burkett.
I'd rather not find a way to work around that issue but to directly solve it.
It's not my team where everyone has browsers up to date.
So thats exactly the thing, I cant trust the group of users to have at least one person who has in mind to update browsers. It's more that kind of "who cares" attitude.
But still I am very gartefull that you took the time to answer!

Answer (score 0):

As for Safari you could scan: https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Introduction/Introduction.html and grab the latest version number from `<nav id="tocContainer">`. Not exactly an API but perhaps kinda stable.